# Partitioning springboot postgres table

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, database-partitioning

I've a springboot app where I need to implement db partitioning (by "range") for posts table based on posted_at attribute value.

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private BigInteger id;

  private String title;

  private Date postedDate;

  .....
}
```

Liquibase migration:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
<changeSet id="00001" author="author">
    <sql splitStatements="true">
        CREATE TABLE posts (
        id bigint primary key,
        title varchar(200),
        posted_at timestamp with time zone) PARTITION BY RANGE (posted_at)
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

When I run the above db migration, Postgres complains that I should add primary key also into the partition keys which I don't really want to. If I remove the primary key from the table, JPA will start throwing exception saying that I cannot have an entity without `@Id` field. How can this be resolved?

PS: I'm using plain sql inside Liquibase migration as liquibase has no direct support for db partitioning.

Comment: "*Liquibase complains*" - no, it's Postgres that complains. And this is a restriction of the current partitioning implementation in Postgres (with no workaround). Why do you think you need to partition anyway? What kind of queries do you have that would benefit from that? Or is this about efficiently getting rid of old posts?

Comment: Hey, yeah..mentioned liquibase by mistake. So I would really be interested in the posts which are posted in the last 1 month (max upto last quarter). If i can partition the data of each month into a different table, that would improve the performance a lot. The parent table will have huge amount of data

Comment: "*the posts which are posted in the last month*" can easily be supported with a non-partitioned table and a btree index on `posted_at`. What exactly do you consider "huge"?

Comment: Let me make it clear:
1. By huge, I meant more than 50 million records out of which 95% of records are not going to fetched from db.
2. Having a `posts` table here in this example doesn't mean I'm working on some posts. I don't really want to disclose my domain entities

Comment: That's not "huge" by today's standards and doesn't really require partitioning. Go with a regular btree index first, maybe a filtered index. The only reason to use partitioning with a table of that (moderate) size would be to be able to quickly delete old rows (by dropping the partition)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) But I would really appreciate if you can suggest me a way to go forward with my current plan

Comment: As I already wrote: that is a restriction that you can't work around. You will either need to teach your obfuscation layer to work with that table (without a primary key) or you need to ditch the strategy to partition the table. Does JPA really verify that  `id` is defined as the PK in the database? Can't you just get away with a simple index on that column? Note that updates (or deletes) that do **not** include the partition key will then be extremely slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213174/discussion-between-vijith-mv-and-a-horse-with-no-name).